# How can I show which files were auto-merged from pull?

Tags: git, merge

Having done a pull (from remote origin), git threw up my default (vi) editor asking me to explain the merge.  I'm assuming this was needed to cover the auto-merge performed by git, because otherwise, the pull just goes through to the next command prompt.

I would like to see which files were auto-merges, so I can see what other people are working on that I'm also working on.  Is there a command that does this or do I need to look through git's logs?

This is not quite the same question as [How to get list of git auto merge files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595124/how-to-get-list-of-git-auto-merge-files)

Answer (score 1):

As with the linked question, you really have to define what you mean by "auto-merge".  (And as always, we should start by defining `git pull`: it's really just `git fetch`, to obtain any commits from the remote that you don't have in your own Git repository yet, followed by `git merge`, to merge your current branch—whatever that is—with the other Git's branch-tip commit that `git fetch` just found.)

It's worth thinking about the merge process—what I like to call *merge as a verb*, where you tell Git to merge two particular commits, the `--ours` and `--theirs`, or left-and-right, or local-and-remote, or for short, *L* and *R*.  The *L* (left/local/`--ours`) commit is, at least for normal commands, always the `HEAD` (current) commit.  The *R* commit is the one you pick, or with `git pull`, have the pull code pick based on what it gets from the remote Git.  The `git merge` command doesn't always do this!  Sometimes, it is possible for `git merge` to skip the merge-as-a-verb process part entirely, doing what Git calls a *fast forward*.  But in that case, you never get the editor session asking you to explain the merge, so in this case, you are getting a real merge.

Anyway, the merge process takes these two commits, the *L* and *R* commits, and finds, from the commit graph inside your repository, which commit is the *merge base* of these two commits.  Using `git log --graph`—or as someone put it, "help from A DOG", **A**ll **D**ecorate **O**neline **G**raph, `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`—you can have Git draw you an ASCII-art chart of what's in your repository, and try to read the graph out of there.  In some cases it's pretty clear; in others it's very hard to tell.  I like to draw the graph horizontally for StackOverflow postings:

```
          o--L   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
         /
...--o--B
         \
          o--R   <-- origin/somebranch
```

The commits that are only on your own branch are, in this case, along the top; the commits that are only on the `origin/` version of your branch, as brought in by the `git fetch` step, are along the bottom; and the commits that are on *both* are in the middle.  The last such commit, "closest to" both *L* and *R*, is the merge base commit *B*.

You don't have to find *B* on your own—Git computes it, and you can find out what Git computed by running:

```
git merge-base --all HEAD <other-commit>
```

where *`<other-commit>`* is something (like the hash ID, or the `origin/somebranch` name) that identifies commit *R*.  If this prints out multiple commit hash IDs, we're in a bit of trouble here.  Git *does* handle this, but we now have to go into the difference between `-s recursive` and `-s resolve`.  But that's rare, so we can just ignore it and pretend it never happens.<sup>1</sup> :-)

Anyway, now that we have all three commit IDs, we can now do what Git will do:

`git diff --find-renames B L`   *what did we change in `--ours`?*
`git diff --find-renames B R`   *what did they change in `--theirs`?*

The result of all this diff-ing tells us which files we and they changed, renamed, deleted, or added, plus what *lines* changed.  Git uses this information—obtained in a more optimal way internally, but with the same effect—to do the merging.

Unfortunately, if all goes well, by the time you're in the editor session trying to describe the merge, all of the above information is *gone*.  What you have left is whatever is in the index (staging area) and work-tree, which is just the result of the merge.  Moreover, Git won't tell you the hash ID of the merge base *B*.  If you at least had that, you could re-run the two `git diff` commands and pick through them.

If you avoid `git pull` entirely, and do your own `git fetch` and then inspect things and *then* `git merge` if you think a merge is appropriate, this gives you a lot more room to work.  You can figure out what commit(s) is/are the base(s) *B* and run your own quick `git diff`s (perhaps using `git diff --find-renames --name-status`, for instance, to just see which *files* are affected and how—created, modified, deleted, and/or renamed).  Now you'll have a pretty good idea of what `git merge` will do *before* you run `git merge`, so that by the time you end up in the editor, you know what to write!

---

<sup>1</sup>The way to make it happen, if you want to for some strange reason, is to do "criss-cross merges": merge one branch into another, then do the same merge in the opposite direction.  You have to force Git to not do a fast-forward not-really-a-merge for the second merge to occur at all.  Once you have this pair of merges in place, both merges become "equally close" to the two branch tips later.